# C++ Take a type as a parameter of an unknown class function?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a class function take another class unknown function. I hope that made any sense. What I am trying to do is... if button1 (or any declared button) is clicked, it will execute whatever function (any "void function") that was inputted into the first parameter of function Event__MouseClicked.

```
bool MouseClicked( void ){ /**/ };

namespace XE
{
    class Window
    {
    public:
        const char* Title;
    };

    class Button
    {
    public:
        void Event__MouseClicked( void( *Function )( void ) ) {
            if( MouseClicked( ) )
                ( *Function )( );
        }
    };
};

class XorrWindow1 : public XE::Window
{
public:
    XorrWindow1( void ) {
        Initialize( );
    }
protected:
    ~XorrWindow1( void );
private:
    XE::Button Button1;
    XE::Button Button2;
private:
    // EVENT PROTOTYPES
    void DoSomething( void );
    void RandomFunction( void );

    void Initialize( void )
    {
        // INITIALIZE CONTROLS
        // AND OTHER STUFF BELOW
        this->Title = "XorrWindow1";

        // How can I resolve this problem?
        this->Button1.Event__MouseClicked( &XorrWindow1::DoSomething );
        this->Button2.Event__MouseClicked( &XorrWindow1::RandomFunction );
    };
};

void XorrWindow1::DoSomething( void ) {
    ::MessageBoxA( NULL, this->Title, "Button1 clicked!", MB_OK );
};

void XorrWindow1::RandomFunction( void ) {
    ::MessageBoxA( NULL, this->Title, "Button2 clicked!", MB_OK );
};
```

The error is this:

```
'XE::Button::Event__MouseClicked' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__thiscall XorrWindow1::* )(void)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void)'
```

I absolutely understand what caused the error. But I don't know how to fix it because it must be able to take any unknown function of class Window1.

Comment: why not use pure virtual functions?

Comment: Like this? virtual void Event__MouseClicked(...). Just Googled some short info about virtual functions. Seems interesting. I'll go study about it.

Comment: @Xorr: Don't wrap code in `<code>…</code>`. Just indent it by at least four spaces.

Comment: Class methods are not like functions. You cannot use a function pointer to  a class member method. But, anyway, I don't think it is the best design for your problem

Comment: @Xorr to be a **pure** virtual function you would need:  void Event__MouseClicked(...)=0;   Being _pure_ forces derived classes to declare and provide a function implementation.  It's not strictly necessary to make it pure though for what you want.

Comment: @Xorr - also lookup the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) - you'll end up with a more maintainable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Karel Petranek said, you need templates to accommodate all cases. Here is the *most* generic method (utilized by STL everywhere):

```
template<typename f>
void Event__MouseClicked(f&& func)
{
    if( MouseClicked( ) )
        func();
}
```

Basically `Event__MouseClicked` accepts a callable object. In your case you would call it like Marcelo Cantos described:

```
Button1.Event__MouseClicked([&]{ DoSomething(); });
```

But the benefit of this method is that passing *any* callable object that takes no arguments into `Event__MouseClicked` will compile and work. You can pass a function pointer, the result of `std::bind`, a `std::function`, a lambda, etc etc.

This is more optimal than forcibly accepting a `std::function` in some cases, for example when accepting a straight function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass a member function pointer as a free function pointer, since there is no way to capture `this` and pass it in as required.

There are many and varied solutions to this problem. The most elegant, if you have C++11, is to pass a `std::function<void()>`:

```
virtual void Event__MouseClicked(const std::function<void()>& f) {
    if (MouseClicked()) f();
}
⋮
Button1.Event__MouseClicked([&]{ DoSomething(); });
```

> **EDIT:** I almost forgot to mention that with lambdas, you can even do away with the callback member functions:
>
> ```
> Button1.Event__MouseClicked([&]{
>     ::MessageBoxA( NULL, this->Title, "Button1 clicked!", MB_OK );
> });
> ```

Because this isn't a template function, you can override it in derived classes. Note, however, that GUI frameworks don't generally require that you derive from classes like `Button` in order to customise their behaviour, and they also don't pass the callback in as part of the event. The common pattern is for the button to hold onto the callback function and invoke it as appropriate. E.g.:

```
class Button {
⋮
public:
    void onClicked(std::function<void(Button*)>& f) { clicked_ = f; }
    void click() { clicked_(this); }
private:
    std::function<void(Button*)> clicked_;

    // Internal click handler responds to OS click events.
    void handleClickEvent(…) { clicked_(this); }
};
```

The above isn't the world's best design, but it should give you a sense of what I'm talking about.

Comment: You dont need C++11 for this, just use boost::function wich is the same as std::funtion

Comment: @Industrial-antidepressant: That only addresses half the picture. Without C++11, constructing the callback is vastly more painful for anything but the most trivial callbacks.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: Without lambda you have to use boost::bind or std::bind. Yes it have a little strange syntax

Comment: @Industrial-antidepressant: It's more than a little strange, and extremely limited. For instance, how would you backport this callback lambda: `[&]{ int n = 0; char buf[99]; sprintf(buf, "Called %d times", ++n); MessageBox(…buf…); }`? (To be used as a stored lambda, of course, not the way the OP did it.)

Comment: @MarceloCantos There is absolutely no lambda you can't 'back port' to use a functor & std::bind. I am pro lambdas and personally never use bind, but bind is *not* more limiting than lambdas, in fact it's **less** limiting because it allows for template arguments for the function operator (something lambdas would be far superior if they had)

Comment: @Dave: I misspoke. Yes, you can do anything with boost lambda. It's just convoluted and difficult to write, read and maintain. So much so that most programmers decided that that particular learning curve wasn't worth climbing (and we all breathed a sigh of relief when lambdas showed up). That's what I meant by "extremely limiting".

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: boost lambda is another story. Boost::bind is just a method or function binder class.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use templates to accommodate for all possible classes:

```
        template <typename T>
        void Event__MouseClicked(T *object, void( T::*Function )( void ) ) {
            if( MouseClicked( ) )
                ( object->*Function )( );
        }
```

Use:

```
this->Button2.Event__MouseClicked( this, &XorrWindow1::RandomFunction );
```

Note though that you will lose the ability to override this method in subclasses as templated functions cannot be virtual. You also need to pass the "this" pointer along with the method pointer.

Comment: Thank you for resolving my problem. I've just learned something new.